# How can I detect current device is Android Tablet?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently android application. In this application, I've added following line to hide topbar of android.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

In this case, when users want to enter setting of my apps in phone, they can press "menu" button of Android phone. But for Samsung Galaxy tab2 7.0, there is no menu button in it. That's why I want to know how can I detect current access device is tablet or not in my apps. If tablet, I want to display toolbar of Android in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Your Galaxy Tab is running Honeycomb or higher, which means that the old Options Menu has been deprecated in favor of Action Bar.  That having been said, there's still a menu icon in the title bar (a square with a slash through it in Honeycomb and three square dots in Jelly Bean).  If your user clicks that, they get your standard options menu (without menu item icons, however).

The alternative is to run ActionBar Sherlock to give your apps action bars, regardless of OS version.

If you insist on doing your own branching based on OS version, try this:

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
{
    // Gingerbread and earlier
}
else
{
    // Honeycomb and later
}
```

Comment: Now my Galaxy Tab2 7.0 is Jellybean and my SIII is either. That's why we cannot detect based my OS version. How about detect by screen size?